# Spring HATEOAS and Entity DTO - problem with ModelAssembler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dto, spring-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm developing Spring HATEOAS REST api. **Now I encountered a need to hide some fields of Employee class** (I want to hide some of them).
As far as i understand DTO (data transfer objects) must be used. So i created new class (EmployeeDTO) with only this fields, that I need. I am using `ModelMapper` to map appropriate fields.

**So now, I have a problem with data types. Do i have to change all return values in my Controller from Employee to EmployeeDTO? And then change everything in ModelAssembler?**

Or maybe DTO class should `extends RepresentationModel`? (This forces to extends it in Entity too).
Looking forward for your help, all of this looks kinda messy (changing all return types) and I feel like there should be smarter solution.

That's how am I doing it right now:

Methods in EmployeeController:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = "application/hal+json")
    public EntityModel<Employee> getEmployeeById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<Employee> employee = employeeService.findById(id);
        return employeeModelAssembler.toModel(employee.get());
}

@GetMapping(value = "", produces = "application/hal+json")
    public CollectionModel<EntityModel<Employee>> getAllEmployees() {
        List<Employee> employeesList = EmployeeService.findall();
        return employeeModelAssembler.toCollectionModel(EmployeesList);
}
```

EmployeeModelAssembler (autowired in Controller):

```
public class EmployeeModelAssembler implements RepresentationModelAssembler<Employee, EntityModel<Employee>> {

    @Override
    public EntityModel<Employee> toModel(Employee employee) {
        EntityModel<Employee> employeeEntityModel = EntityModel.of(employee);

        Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).getEmployeeById(employee.getId())).withSelfRel();
        employeeEntityModel.add(selfLink);

        return employeeEntityModel;
    }

    @Override
    public CollectionModel<EntityModel<Employee>> toCollectionModel(Iterable<? extends Employee> entities) {

        List<Employee> employeesList = (List<Employee>) entities;
        List<EntityModel<Employee>> employeeEML = employeesList.stream().map(this::toModel).collect(Collectors.toList());

        Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).getAllEmployees()).withSelfRel();

        return CollectionModel.of(employeeEML, selfLink);
    }
}
```

## EDIT

This is the way I'm accessing this hal+json response in another controller. The goal is to get List of EmployeeDTO objects:

```
String uri = "http://localhost:8080/api/employees";

Traverson traverson = new Traverson(URI.create(uri), MediaTypes.HAL_JSON);
Traverson.TraversalBuilder tb = traverson.follow("href");

ParameterizedTypeReference<CollectionModel<EmployeeDTO>> typeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<CollectionModel<EmployeeDTO>>() {};
CollectionModel<EmployeeDTO> resEmployees = tb.toObject(typeReference);
Collection<EmployeeDTO> employees = resEmployees.getContent();

ArrayList<EmployeesDTO> employeesList = new ArrayList<>(employees);

for(EmployeesDTO x : employeesList) {
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(x.getLinks());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to decouple the resource exposed by your API from your JPA entity, which is a good idea, you will have to update your controller to handle the appropriate types.

See the example below:

Firstly, let's suppose you have the following DTO:

```
public class EmployeeDTO extends RepresentationModel<EmployeeDTO> {
      private long id;
      private String surname;
      private String departmentId;

      // getters and setters
}
```

Note how I'm not mixing your JPA entity (Employee) with the DTO.

Now your controller should be updated to return the appropriate type.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = "application/hal+json")
public EmployeeDTO getEmployeeById(@PathVariable long id) {
       Optional<Employee> employee = employeeService.findById(id);
       return employeeModelAssembler.toModel(employee.get());
}

@GetMapping(value = "", produces = "application/hal+json")
public CollectionModel<EmployeeDTO> getAllEmployees() {
    List<Employee> employeesList = employeeService.findAll();
    return employeeModelAssembler.toCollectionModel(employeesList);
}
```

And an example of a ModelAssembler

```
@Component
public class EmployeeModelAssembler implements RepresentationModelAssembler<Employee, EmployeeDTO> {

    @Override
    public EmployeeDTO toModel(Employee employee) {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        EmployeeDTO employeeDto = modelMapper.map(employee, EmployeeDTO.class);

        Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class).getEmployeeById(employee.getId())).withSelfRel();
        employeeDto.add(selfLink);

        return employeeDto;
    }

    @Override
    public CollectionModel<EmployeeDTO> toCollectionModel(Iterable<? extends Employee> employeesList) {
       ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
       List<EmployeeDTO> employeeDTOS = new ArrayList<>();

       for (Employee employee : employeesList){
           EmployeeDTO employeeDto = modelMapper.map(employee, EmployeeDTO.class);
           employeeDto.add(linkTo(methodOn(EmployeeController.class)
                                .getEmployeeById(employeeDto.getId())).withSelfRel());
           employeeDTOS.add(employeeDto);
        }

        return new CollectionModel<>(employeeDTOS);
    }
}
```

I tested it and got the following response, assuming I have an employees endpoint

get employees/1

```
{
"id": 1,
"surname": "teste",
"departmentId": "1",
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees/1"
    }
}
}
```

get employees

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "employeeDtoList": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "surname": "teste",
                "departmentId": "1",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees/1"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "surname": "teste",
                "departmentId": "2",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/employees/2"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is invaluable help. Would you also be able to help with parsing this hal+json back in another controller? (Probably with usage of Traverson). Ther's nearly no information at all about that. If you say you would, then I will create new post and send link to you/

Comment: @Nickname11 probably, I'm not online for much longer today, but you should post the question anyway. If I'm still here I will take a look. Traverson seems a good choice indeed. Send the link to me when you create! See ya

Comment: actually, I think I managed to deal with it myself (added as a EDIT in this post), again - my solution is messy, but it's working, but part that's bother me the most is ```traverson.follow("href")```